# QDoubleSpinBox does not allow negative values despite setting minimum

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, c++17

In QT, I'm trying to have a spinbox to represent a power level in decibels, which goes to negative infinity for power levels less than 1.

I call:

```
this->ui->powerdbBox->setMinimum(DBL_MIN);
```

But I cannot enter values less than 0, still. I tried setting the minimum to -1 with the same results.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

as per [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits) DBL_MIN is

> minimum, normalized, **positive** value of double.

try setting the minimum of your spinBox to `std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest()`

Comment: Not only did this work, but it informed me of another way to get the min and max of different types in C++.